Using standard locators instead in Playwright library
I'm using Playwright as library for testing with Cucumber as test runner. The template which I am using is forked from here.
The template uses only the Playwright locators using CSS or XPath. Is it possible to use the Playwright built-in locators instead of the  CSS or XPath locator?
The key difference is the Playwright I'm using as library instead of the Playwright test runner.

What do you mean by "is it possible"? It is. Go right ahead! That said, this template looks pretty weak, to be honest. I'd avoid it.
